# en el EvenListener input, ¿hay alguna forma de elegir el elemento hijo con el que quieres que se dispare

Tags: javascript, html

Trato de que un especifico <option dentro de un <select dispare una funcion al elgirlo (el de +) pero los event listeners no parecen funcionar en los <option, la documentacion del eventlistener me parecio algo confusa y no estoy muy seguro si es posible desde el event listener input, se me ocurre un if como ultima opcion, pero no estoy muy seguro de la gramatica, si esa fuera la unica opcion ¿como deberia buscar el tema?

```
<select class="select" name="anaquel" id="anamas">
       <option value="">1</option>
       <option  value="">+</option>

     </select>
```

```
    <script>
     let newoption = document.createElement("option") 
     var id = document.querySelector(".id")
     var masanaquel = document.getElementById("anamas")
     var select = document.getElementsByClassName("select")[0]
     

         
         
     function addAnaquel() {
       console.log("cambiado")
     select.appendChild(newoption);
     console.log(select)
     }


  
     masanaquel.addEventListener("input", addAnaquel)
     
     
         </script>
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentas, la opción que veo es crear un evento `onchange` en el `select` y controlar internamente el valor del `option`:

```js
// Crea el evento change
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', (e) => {

  let el = e.currentTarget;
  
  // Comprueba el valor del option seleccionado y ejecuta
  // una acción si es el esperado (en este caso, +).
  if (el.options[el.selectedIndex].value === '+')
    console.log('Event action');

});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="test">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>+</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```